# MemTest86+ shows errors while MemTest86 doesn't?

Tags: memory, cpu, memtest86+, memtest86

I bought a new PC that has been crashing in exactly 1 game (fortnite) so I decided to do memory tests. I ran prime95 and memtest64 and there were no errors at all. I ran 3/3 passes of memtest86 and it also reported no errors. However running a single pass of memtest86+ shows me an error in the exact same bit at different memory addresses. That being the 5th byte from the left. I have 2 modules of 16 GB each bought as a 2x16 DDR5 5200 pack.
On JEDEC speeds I have no errors, the tests above were running on EXPO 2. Expo 1 shows significantly more failures in every single test.

My question is why is memtest86+ failing but not the other tests? And if indeed its result are accurate, what could 1 bit error mean? The errors are spanning all the cpu cores at all ram addresses, so it can't be that both memory sticks are bad at the same spot, could the bus of the cpu or the ram be the issue?

[image: memtest86+ results]

Comment: Have you tried re-seating your ram in it's sockets? or swapping sticks around to see if the same error occurs ?

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft no I have not, I will do now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @JamesP that's why I'm asking because it didn't make sense to me that it says I have 7700MHz with CAS 128?? So maybe it is erroring because it is doing the test at incorrect assumptions,

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft I did that, and ran 3 passes, and the error is now gone (for now). So I guess that was maybe the issue! Thanks!